# Two different supremum, are they the same?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a normed linear space, and let $Y$ be a subspace of $X$.

Let $l\in X'$, the dual of $X$.

Are these two supremum the same?

1. $$\sup_{\|x+y\|\leq 1,x\in X, y\in Y}|l(x+y)|$$
2. $$\sup_{\|z\|\leq 1, z\in X}|l(z)|$$

---

I tried to prove they are the same via the following: Let $A=\{x+y\mid\|x+y\|\leq 1,x\in X, y\in Y\}$, let $B=\{z\mid \|z\|\leq 1, z\in X\}$.

Any $x+y$ in $A$ is also in $B$ since $x+y\in X$.

Any $z$ in $B$ can be written as $z+0$ which is in $A$ since $0\in Y$. Thus $A$ and $B$ are the same sets and thus the supremum must be the same.

Anything wrong with the above reasoning? It seems slightly weird that they are equal because one supremum is dependent on $Y$, and the other isn't.

Comment: It only _pretends_ to be dependent on $Y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you show, $A=B$. This not different than
$$
\sup\{|f(x)|:\ x\in\mathbb R, |x|\leq1\}=\sup\{|f(x+y):\ x\in\mathbb R, y\in\mathbb Q, |x+y|\leq1\}
$$